# Is it okay to add custom keys to the object in a progressive web app `manifest.json` file?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I want to add a custom key to the `manifest.json` file for a progressive web app.

The MDN page doesn't mention custom keys:

- [Web App Manifest | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

The spec:

- [Web App Manifest](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/)

includes this text in [the section "3.1 Media type registration"](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#media-type-registration) under a sub-heading "Security and privacy considerations":

> As the manifest format is JSON and will commonly be encoded using [[UNICODE]](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#bib-unicode), the security considerations described in [[ECMA-404]](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#bib-ecma-404) and [[UNICODE-SECURITY]](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#bib-unicode-security) apply. In addition, because there is no way to prevent developers from including custom/unrestrained data in a [manifest](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#dfn-manifest), implementors need to impose their own implementation-specific limits on the values of otherwise unconstrained member types, e.g. to prevent denial of service attacks, to guard against running out of memory, or to work around platform-specific limitations.

Are there known limitations or restrictions on the use of custom keys in `manifest.json` files?

Comment: What’s your use case? It doesn’t make much sense to put there anything browsers wouldn’t use.

Comment: @emix I actually want to add a comment but I figured there might be other use cases; hence the generality of the question. I was mainly curious whether custom keys would break anything in any browsers but maybe there are other problems too.

Comment: I’m pretty sure browsers will simply ignore something they don’t understand.

Comment: @emix Any links for that? Chrome seems to be ignoring the custom key I added.

Comment: Didn’t I say that already?

Comment: @emix You wrote "I’m pretty sure browsers will simply ignore something they don’t understand.". You neither cited nor referenced any specific evidence and you also qualified your statement with "pretty sure". A link to some evidence beyond your comment would be helpful – if you have one to share. I weakly confirmed your statement by writing that I found your claim to be true when I tested it on one computer in one browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard SO-59512547

> Browsers shall ignore any values starting with `X-` which is a common
> abbreviation for custom headers in HTTP and E-Mail. As they are to be
> used exclusively by developers.

My use case is sending boot up data early with HTTP 2.0, things that would normally be in headers or env variables, but that I would non the less want to keep dynamic... such as socket endpoints, custom loading UI and console logging level. Always loading manifest.json is extremely common, and thus it can serve as standard boot config file better than a custom named json file that we would have to tell the server we want prefectched along any request for index.html.

Australians, Mooners, Martians will thank me.

Comment: A Google search just now didn't return any seemingly relevant results for "SO-59512547". Can you share a link to what that refers to?